# Wordpress Meta Slider Snippet in a div

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a custom HTML/CSS/Jquery Wordpress theme, I installed Meta Slider, It provided me with a snippet and a template shortcode that it said to copy into my template,

Say

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=37]"); 
?>
```

But I have made a dive in my HTML page/Template explicitly

```
</nav>
<div id="sliderTX">

</div>
```

for the slider to occupy, is there any way i could add that shortcode and hence the slider into the webpage?

http://i.gyazo.com/909725970e3f9a65c2adee27a20ffb1f.png

The red block.

Comment: you can add that shortcode between the div

Comment: simply '<div> <?php echo do_shortcode("[data]"); ?> </div>' would do?